# Correct way to fetch data via API before page is mounted in Nuxt 3

Tags: hook, nuxt3

I would like to load profile data via API before page is mounted so that I can show profile data on the page. I have created a `onBeforeMount` VUE hook to load the data. My profile data is then stored in the composable so that I can reuse on other pages. However, when page loads I get an error that my profile composable is equal to null, despite the fact that I see API returning the data. What am I doing wrong? Should I use Nuxt hook instead?

My page:

```
<script setup>
const profileStore = profileState();

onBeforeMount(async () => {
    if(!profileStore.value){
        const {data, error} = await useFetch("/api/profile");
        if(error.value){
            return;
        };
        profileStore.value = data.value;
    };
});
</script>
```

My API:

```
import { serverSupabaseClient } from "#supabase/server";
import { serverSupabaseUser } from "#supabase/server";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const client = serverSupabaseClient(event);
    const user = await serverSupabaseUser(event);

    if(user){
        const { data, error } = await client.from("profiles").select().eq("user", user.id).single();
        if(error){
            throw createError({statusMessage: error.message});
        } else {
            return data;
        };
    } else {
        throw createError({statusMessage: "Unauthorized"});
    };
});
```